# SQL - Flag consecutive value change in column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm going to do my best to explain my issue.

I have a dataset that looks similar to the following:

```
Row#    CusCode Status
1   100101  Green
2   100101  Green
3   100101  Red
4   100101  Amber
5   100101  Amber
6   100101  Green
7   100101  Red
8   100101  Red
9   100101  Red
10  200909  Red
11  200909  Amber
12  200909  Green
13  200909  Red
```

I am trying to get this view as a next step:

```
Row#    CusCode Status  Required
1   100101  Green   1
2   100101  Green   1
3   100101  Red 2
4   100101  Amber   3
5   100101  Amber   3
6   100101  Green   4
7   100101  Red 5
8   100101  Red 5
9   100101  Red 5
10  200909  Red 1
11  200909  Amber   2
12  200909  Green   3
13  200909  Red 4
```

Last step is for the dataset to look as follows:

```
CusCode Status  Required
100101  Green   1
100101  Red 2
100101  Amber   3
100101  Green   4
100101  Red 5
200909  Red 1
200909  Amber   2
200909  Green   3
200909  Red 4
```

**Please note the following:**

- I require that a counter be created based on the status change, irrespective if the status changes to an earlier status, intention is to flag consecutive duplicate records - Table 2 provides an illustration of this.
- The dataset contains multiple records
- The order in which the Status is displayed is most important and must output in the same order (Table 3 provides this view).

Your assistance will be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Please decide which database you're using. Please convert your screenshots to text, or even better, give us a link to an sqlfiddle with data already populated. Please show what youve tried so far. Note, we're not a free code writing service

Comment: do NOT use "images of data"  ( or we might start "images of queries" as answers....  )

Comment: If maintaining the "original order" is vital, please tell us which columns of information can be used to retain that order because in SQL tables are NOT "ordered". Are there any date/time columns that can be used for this? is there an auto-incrementing integer id field? This information will be critical

Comment: @CaiusJard - I've converted to text and using SQL server. I've tried using the LAG function to attain the 'Required' file with no joy. I understand that you are not a free code writing service, just at a dead end with this at current.

Comment: @Used_By_Already - I was hoping to use the 'required' field to maintain the order of the dataset. There is no auto-incrementing field.

Comment: but how do you get the required field if there is nothing to base the order on?  The results cannot be guaranteed if the data isn't reliable... simple as that. Now; **MUST** know what database this is for please. (MysQL? Oracle? Presto? Impala? ...... whatever?) they are all different in some way and affect query syntax.

Comment: Try using `DENSE_RANK()` in SQL Server partitioned by CustomerCode and Order by CustomerCode and Status

Comment: I'm using SQL server 2012 @Used_By_Already
I've tried using the DENSE_RANK (), doesn't provide desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first phase of this I would use `LEAD()` and then this allows me to locate each row that does (or does not) have a change in status. So then delete the unwanted rows, and voila! you have your end result by using `ROW_NUMBER()` on the surviving rows.

Regarding the "original order". You should never rely on the rows of a table being stored in a predictable order. Below I have used a "trick" to fool the `over clause` to apply an order that in effect does nothing and so "hopefully" the rows will be in the desired "original order", however this cannot be guaranteed. In practice it works, but you really should not rely on it. Add a datetime/datetime2 column as each row is created.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8593a/2)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([RowNo] int, [CusCode] int, [Status] varchar(5))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([RowNo], [CusCode], [Status])
VALUES
    (1, 100101, 'Green'),
    (2, 100101, 'Green'),
    (3, 100101, 'Red'),
    (4, 100101, 'Amber'),
    (5, 100101, 'Amber'),
    (6, 100101, 'Green'),
    (7, 100101, 'Red'),
    (8, 100101, 'Red'),
    (9, 100101, 'Red'),
    (10, 200909, 'Red'),
    (11, 200909, 'Amber'),
    (12, 200909, 'Green'),
    (13, 200909, 'Red')
;
```

**Delete Query**:

```
with CTE as (
  select
       *
     , lead(status) over(partition by CusCode order by (select 1)) nxt_status
  from table1
  )
delete from CTE
where status = nxt_status
;
```

**Inspect Query**

```
with CTE as (
  select
       *
     , row_number() over(partition by CusCode order by (select 1)) rn
  from table1
  )
select
*
from CTE
;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8593a/2/0)**:

```
| RowNo | CusCode | Status | rn |
|-------|---------|--------|----|
|     2 |  100101 |  Green |  1 |
|     3 |  100101 |    Red |  2 |
|     5 |  100101 |  Amber |  3 |
|     6 |  100101 |  Green |  4 |
|     9 |  100101 |    Red |  5 |
|    10 |  200909 |    Red |  1 |
|    11 |  200909 |  Amber |  2 |
|    12 |  200909 |  Green |  3 |
|    13 |  200909 |    Red |  4 |
```